# C: Learning about Pointers, printing address FAILS

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am learning C and was writing a small program that prints the address in a pointer, and the addresses value. I see no error with my code just the print statement. But I fell theres something wrong with the way I'm using pointers.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    char a[] = "Hellow World";  // create an arry

    char *ap = a;           // create a pointer and set the address to `a`

    int i = 0;          // create a counter


    while (*ap) // while inside the array
    {
        // print the address and contents of array content
        printf("Addr: %x, %c\n", ap, *ap);

        ap++;   // increment through the array
    }

    // Crash the program, using an array
    for ( ap = a, i = 0; i<20; i++){
        *(ap+i) = '\0';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Compiler:

```
gcc -Wall -g -o bin/pointer2.c source/pointer2.c
```

Error:

```
source/pointer2.c: In function ‘main’:
source/pointer2.c:16:3: warning: format ‘%x’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 2 has type ‘char *’ [-Wformat=]
   printf("Addr: %x, %c\n", ap, *ap);
```

When I try formating for a string instead of hex I get this output.

print statement:

```
printf("Addr: %s, %c\n", ap, *ap);
```

Output:

```
Addr: Hellow World, H
Addr: ellow World, e
Addr: llow World, l
Addr: low World, l
Addr: ow World, o
Addr: w World, w
Addr:  World,  
Addr: World, W
Addr: orld, o
Addr: rld, r
Addr: ld, l
Addr: d, d
```

Comment: for address u can give %p

Comment: And you are accessing illegal address in your final for loop, since sizeof(a) < 20.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `%p` to print a pointer's address, not `%x`. As the warning says, `%x` expects the argument to be an integer, not a pointer.

Comment: I see, for some reason I was thinking I was using the pointer wrong since it was asking for an integer. Thanks for the help, the code works now

Comment: I copied this code from a c learning source, they were on windows xp. Does using %x in the windows environment work? Is it needed or can the windows OS also use %p?

Comment: It will probably work in both environments. The message is just a warning. GCC does extra checking that the Windows compiler doesn't.

Comment: cool that would suck for cross platform development if formating was was too different over multiple OS's.

Comment: You should use the correct code, %p, and then it should work cross-platform.

Comment: Of course you could do `printf("%x", (unsigned int)ap);` but that is only guaranteed to work if the address bus is of the same width as an `int` on your system (which it is on 99.9% of all computers).

Answer (score 0):

From ISO/IEC 9899:TC3

`%x` is desrcibed as:

> o,u,x,X
>
> The unsigned int argument is converted to unsigned octal (o), unsigned
>   decimal (u), or unsigned hexadecimal notation (x or X) in the style dddd; the
>   letters abcdef are used for x conversion and the letters ABCDEF for X
>   conversion. The precision specifies the minimum number of digits to appear;
>   if the value being converted can be represented in fewer digits, it is expanded
>   with leading zeros. The default precision is 1. The result of converting a
>   zero value with a precision of zero is no characters.

instead you should use `%p`
which is described by standard as:

> p
>
> The argument shall be a pointer to void. The value of the pointer is
>   converted to a sequence of printing characters, in an implementation-defined
>   manner.

Answer (score -1):

For printing the address in C use %u instead of %x it will give you in decimal formmat.
and you can use %p it will give you in hex format